# files permission is not changing in windows getting error access is denied

Tags: windows, permissions, command

I used following command:

```
icacls "E:\images\2013\*.*" /grant kamlesh:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

or

```
icacls "E:\images\2013" /grant kamlesh:(OI)(CI)F
```

its not working and i am getting following error:

```
processed file: E:\images\2013\dogs-101a.jpg
E:\images\2013\dogs-103a.jpg: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

how i can get ownership or grant to see my all image files.

Comment: solve my self, just need to open command prompt as admin.

Answer (score 0):

solve my self, just need to open command prompt as admin.

then

enter following commands:

```
takeown /f E:\f\kd\*
icacls "E:\images\kd\*" /grant kamlesh:(OI)(CI)F
```